# Django-allauth restrict registration to list of emails

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm using Django-allauth, I have a list of emails and I want to restrict registration to this list. My idea was to check the signing up user email and, if not in the emails list, stop registration process and redirect. 
As suggested by Chetan Ganji I tried editing allauth.account.views.SignupView but it does not subscribe the form_valid method. How can i do that? Thank you for help

```
from allauth.account.views import SignupView

class AllauthCustomSignupView(SignupView):

    def form_valid(self, form):
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        auth_user_list =    [   'email_1',
                                'email_2',
                                ...
                            ]

        if not any(email in s for s in auth_user_list):
            return reverse('url')
        return super(MySignupView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: you might wanna override some function inside the allauth.account.views.SignupView, as in the above code you are overriding some signal which is sent/called after the user has been signed up successfully.

Comment: you have to override form_valid() method in the above mentioned class, put the above code login inside this method before calling its super method.

Comment: Thank you, i'm following your advice. I edited the code but still not working. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I have also written a new url for the view to point to:
        url(r'^signup/$', AllauthCustomSignupView.as_view(), name="account_signup"),

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by extending the `DefaultAccountAdapter` class. You have to figure out a way to store and fetch the restricted list on demand.
You can then use the adapters and raise validation error in the registration from. Extend a `DefaultAccountAdapter` and override the clean_email method. Create an adapter.py in your project directory and extend the default adapter class.

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
from django.forms import ValidationError

class RestrictEmailAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def clean_email(self,email):
        RestrictedList = ['Your restricted list goes here.']
        if email in RestrictedList
            raise ValidationError('You are restricted from registering. Please contact admin.')
        return email
```

Finally, point the account adapter in settings.py to your extended class.

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'YourProject.adapter.RestrictEmailAdapter'
```

Comment: My solution works. But, this one seems much simpler solution.

Comment: he could write a method on the class RestrictEmailAdapter to return the list of restricted emails from the database using the django ORM. He has to call that method from clean_email().

Comment: You are right, both solutions work. I think this is cleaner. Thank you very much both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with this code

```
class AllauthCustomSignupView(SignupView):

    def form_valid(self, form):
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        auth_user_list =    [   'email_1',
                                'email_2',
                                ...
                            ]

        if email in auth_user_list:
            return reverse('blocked-email') # whatever url, make sure that the url is defined inside form_valid or in approriate location.
        else:
            return super(AllauthCustomSignupView, self).form_valid(form)

class BlockedEmailView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "blocked-email.html"
```

Add below line to your urls.py

```
url(r'^signup/$', views.AllauthCustomSignupView.as_view(), name="signup"),
url(r'^blocked/email$', views.BlockedEmailView.as_view(), name="blocked-email"),
```

Also, you will need to change the action attribute of the form that SignupView has. So, your will have to override the template of that view, keep everything else the same, just change the action to point to "signup/".